# Add testers via Firebase Crashlytics platform

Tags: firebase, twitter-fabric, google-fabric, fabric-beta

Before now in `Fabric Beta`

[image: Fabric: Beta]

I could add new testers via `Add Testers` button:

[image: Fabric: Beta: Add Testers]

How could I add new testers via `Firebase` platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Fabric/Crashlytics Beta is not yet available under the Firebase umbrella. We're working on it, and it will be available later this year under the name App Distribution.

I recommend taking a look at the [Fabric roadmap](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap), which also contains a link to [request early access to Firebase App Distribution](https://appdistro.page.link/alpha-signup-roadmap/).

Comment: Frank, how long does it take to accept the request from Firebase team usually? I had submitted it on that day, I haven't received any response yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds this question. When you go to Firebase console:

1. Select the project you want to manage
2. Go to App Distribution on the menu on the left side. (the main view should display App Distribution title)
3. Select 'Testers & Groups'